# Где хранить пути до изображений на сайте?

Tags: веб-программирование

Насколько я понял сами файлы изображений лучше скидывать в папку img, а вот где держать пути к ним? Нормально ли это делать в базе данных или лучше выбрать что-то получше?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если на вашем проекте существует необходимость загружать пользовательские фотографии, сначала необходимо выбрать принцип их хранения на сервере.

Если вы собираетесь работать с сотнями файлов, стоит выбрать древовидную структуру
Это позволит избежать ситуации с тысячами файлов в одной папке (это тормозит работу файловой системы и вашу собственную). Лучше всего использовать вложенную структуру из папок длинной в два символа:

Comment: и что? Где хранить то путь к изображению?

Comment: Альтернативы две: в файловой системе и в базе данных.

Comment: А что лучше?______

Comment: Вердикт такой. Нельзя сказать, что какой-то из подходов более правильный, т.к. правильность определяется задачей. Более простым является стандартный способ хранения изображений как файлов. Но для некоторых задач более подходят базы данных.